# Botón "atrás" Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, botón

Quisiera saber si es posible poner el botón "atrás" en diferentes Activity de una aplicación. 
Me ha salido un error en el fichero "AndroidManifest" al intentar declarar como PARENT_ACTIVITY en dos activity diferentes. Cada uno con su respectivo padre.

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.MyProject.pruba1Activity"/>
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.MyProject.prueba1Activity" />
```

Si este código lo duplico para sitios diferentes,me ha salido error en la compilación.

En el archivo java he incluido:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

¿Es posible hacerlo para dos Activity diferentes?

Comment: te refieres a apretar el botón de atrás del dispositivo o poner un botón aparte donde ponga atrás?

Comment: Poner el botón "UP" en el Action Bar al lado del título de la app.

Comment: ¿Qué error te reporta? mira el log en Android Studio mientras la lanzas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que llamar al toolbar en la activity que quieres poner el boton.

```
public void llamarToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Luego para darle función:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: //Aquí la funcion para ir a la activity que quieras.

            return true;


    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes implementar el método:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();

        return true;
    }
```

En conjunto con:

```
setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```